# kendo panelbar onSelect event

Tags: kendo-ui

onselect event: when I click on this, this will change the class of element I inside, if I click on another, class of element I previous will change to the original.This is my code, but it does not work.

```
<ul id="type_list">
    <li> <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  file 1</li>
    <li> <i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  file 2</li>
</ul>
// onselect
 function onSelect(e) 
    {   
    $(e.item).find("> .k-link i.fa.fa-file-text-o").attr("class","fa fa-check");
     $(this).find("> .k-link i.fa.fa-check").attr("class","fa fa-file-text-o");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onSelect, first reset all panelbar items to the original class, then set the class of the selected item (you can use jQuery functions [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)):

```
function onSelect(e) 
{ 
   $("#type_list i.fa").removeClass("fa-check").addClass("fa-file-text-o");
   $(e.item).find("i.fa").removeClass("fa-file-text-o").addClass("fa-check");
}
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/InOhoS)**

Answer (score 0):

header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
    <ul id="panelbar">
        <li>
           SECTION1
            <div>sdfsd sfjsdkfsd</div>
        </li>
        <li class="servicetable" id="side-by-side1">
            ENGINE
            <div>asdas asdasd</div>
        </li>
        <li class="servicetable" id="side-by-side2">
            TRANSMISSION
            <div>asdasdas asdasd</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            PERFORMANCE
            <div>There are three types of lists you can use, and this quick guide will show you how to use each. ... However, to create an ordered list, the ol tag is used rather than the ul tag. By ....</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

script:
$(document).ready(function() {
             $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
                 expandMode: "single"

```
         });
     });
```

Style:

.servicetable
         {
        vertical-align:top;
         border:1px solid #000;
         list-style:none;
         padding:2px;
         width:49.2%;
         display:inline-block !important;
         }
         div.k-content{
         width: 95vw;
         padding:5px !important;
         }
         #side-by-side2 div.k-content{
         margin-left: -49vw;
         }